# How exactly does bitlocker protect my data?

Tags: bitlocker

I presume that if I set a password for my computer and then protect the C: drive with bitlocker then not even FBI can do anything about it.

Without password for my user, will bitlocker has any uses?

Comment: +1, nice question. I think the key here is sending feedback to Bitlocker for changes regarding when devices should dismount as well, i.e. on sleep, on restart, on wake, etc as these seem like the most obvious flaws.

Comment: None of the answer, answer my question. For example, if I do not password protect my computer, then anyone that want to access my computer can just access it right? So does bitlocker requires me to use password for my computer?

Comment: I am never asked for bitlocker password. Just windows password.

Comment: Are you trying to password protect a drive or a file? Bitlocker only prompts for a password upon mount of a drive or vhd file, not upon windows login.

Comment: @JimThio bitlocker can be set up to keep the encryption keys on the TPM (a good thing) but often the TPM is then set up to not require a PIN (very bad). If you use the TPM without PIN, then no password is required to boot to Windows. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decrypting software is available but most of the time it requires access to your memory first. Since memory is volatile, the minute you restart and your encrypted device is dismounted it becomes impossible to decrypt. There are [computers being built](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2320910/nsa-is-designing-a-quantum-supercomputer) for the sole purpose of decryption which will make it easier to crack depending on the type of encryption algorithm you use.

The password you set for a user account on windows when you login is probably the easiest thing to bypass, software like Trinity can simply remove the password of a user account and let anyone in. In the case of theft, the thief could easily remove your hard drives and put them in another computer as secondary hard drives which would enable them access to their contents.

However, Bitlocker works differently. With Bitlocker one can encrypt a single file or an entire drive with an algorithm that requires a brute force attack in order to bypass.

[image: Bitlocker UI]

So when you access a Bitlocker drive you will be prompted for a password which, when correct, will allow you access to its contents. This occurs because the password is being used to decrypt the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Bypassing your password is easy. Search for "windows password reset" for many possible options.

Bitlocker is **not** secure if someone has physical access to your computer.

From [First commercial tool to crack BitLocker arrives](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/12/first-commercial-tool-cracks-bitlocker/) :

> Passware, a software firm that provides password recovery, decryption, and evidence discovery software for computer forensics, has updated its flagship application this week to support breaking Microsoft's BitLocker hard drive encryption. Passware Kit Forensic version 9.5 can recover encryption keys for hard drives protected with BitLocker in just a few minutes. It scans a physical memory image file of the target computer and extracts all the encryption keys for a given BitLocker disk. As a result, Passware has crowned itself the creator of the first commercially available software to crack BitLocker Drive Encryption.

Passware claims that full disk encryption was a major problem for investigators and that **its tool helps police, law enforcement, and private investigators bypass BitLocker encryption for seized computers**. That may be, but since this is a commercially available product, anyone with $795 can now circumvent the encryption. Add to that the fact that previous versions of this software have been pirated (version 9.0 was released earlier this year), and it's only a matter of time before even the price point doesn't matter.

See also [Researchers break into BitLocker](http://www.zdnet.com/researchers-break-into-bitlocker-3039926434/) and the full paper [Attacking the BitLocker Boot Process](http://testlab.sit.fraunhofer.de/downloads/Publications/Attacking_the_BitLocker_Boot_Process_Trust2009.pdf)

Comment: However, how do you get the "physical memory image file" containing the encryption keys when the computer is powered off? No dice.

Comment: @Anton Decryption keys can also be derived from hibernation files if a target PC is turned off.

Comment: The hibernation file must of course be on the encrypted volume.

Answer (score 1):

Bitlocker does full disk encryption. The encryption keys are kept in RAM when the OS is running.

There are ways to bypass the Windows logon screen. Also, when the computer is running, the bitlocker encryption keys are in RAM and with the right equipment it is possible to access it. Therefore it is important that the adversary cannot boot the computer to Windows or get physical access to the running computer.

You need to take at least the following safety measures:

- Never leave the computer running unattended. This includes suspend mode. Hibernate is OK.
- Store the bitlocker key in the TPM, with a strong pass phrase.
- Back up the bit locker recovery key in a safe place or you will lose access to your data yourself when the TPM acts up.

Comment: The hibernation file must of course be on the encrypted volume and you need the encryption keys to access the encrypted volume.